# how to print landscape automatically with Mozilla browser?

Tags: html, css, printing, mozilla

I've been using the script

```
 @page {
 size:A4 landscape;
}
```

but it only works in the Chrome browser. How to print landscape automatically with a Mozilla browser ??

Comment: PHP is a server side language. It has nothing to do with HTML, CSS, printing and browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, last I recall hearing is that the `@page` rule in CSS has been cut down in scope.  (If anyone knows otherwise, please correct me)

If you need to have your PHP page print reliably in Mozilla (and all other browsers), what about using server-side PDF generation?  The functions in PHP to support this can be found at http://www.php.net/pdf

Comment: yes you right @page rule in CSS,i've been changed my question. How to print landscape automatically with a Mozilla browser?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox [does not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@page) the [CSS3 Module: Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/). If you want to have a document thats looks the same on every printer use a PDF, since you have no control over custom extensions and user defined stylesheets.

You could try something like

```
@media print {
  html { width:29.7cm;height:21cm;}
  body{margin:3cm;}
}
```

but we all know about the inconsistent browser handling of the `@media` rules :/.